# Hello how can i draw a Triangle using CSS?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

Please help me i need your suggestions.

Comment: Google...

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

    border-left: 60px solid green;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 0):

Look [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) for instructions on how to use CSS to draw a triangle.
Here is an example:

```
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

    border-left: 60px solid green;
}
```

CSS tricks can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com)